# Is creating "testable code" always consistent with following the best OOP design principles?

Tags: unit-testing, oop, testing, design-patterns, functional-programming

This is perhaps too general/subjective a question for StackOverflow, but I've been dying to ask it somewhere.

Maybe it's because I'm new to the software engineering world, but it seems like the buzzwords I've been hearing the past couple years are like

- *"testable code"*
- *"test coverage"*
- *"pure functions"*
- *"every code path in your entire application covered by a test that is a pure in-memory test -- doesn't open database connections or anything. Then we'll know that the code we deploy is guaranteed to work" (yea, right lol)*

and sometimes I find this hard to reconcile with the way I want to design my application.

For example, one thing that happens often is I have a complex algorithm inside one or more private methods

```
private static void DoFancyAlgorithm(string first, string second)
{
   // ... 
}
```

and I want or need it to have test coverage.

Well, since you're not supposed to directly test `private` methods, I have 3 options:

- make the method accessible for test (maybe `InternalsVisibleTo` in C# or `friend` in C++)
- move the logic to a separate class whose "single responsibility" is dealing with this logic, even though from an OOP perspective I believe the logic should be confined to the class it is currently inside, and test that separate class
- leave the code as-is and spend 100+ hours figuring out to setup the scenario where I indirectly test the logic of the method. Sometimes this means creating ridiculous mock objects to inject in the class with.

So my question is:

> Is creating "testable code" always consistent with the best OOP
>   practice or is there sometimes a tradeoff?

Comment: This depends on how you define '*best OOP practice*'.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a testable code has of course consequences on the applicative design.
So it happens that you may do some trade-off on the design but this is generally limited.
Besides unit testing of the component API focuses on input and output of the tested functions.
So I have difficulties to understand as you may finish in such a bad smell:

> leave the code as-is and spend 100+ hours figuring out to setup the
>   scenario where I indirectly test the logic of the method. Sometimes
>   this means creating ridiculous mock objects to inject in the class
>   with.

In most of cases as a setup/understanding of the unit test scenarios consumes so much time, it very probably means that :

- the component API is not clear.
- and/or you mock too many things and so you should wonder whether you should not favor integration tests (without mocks or by limiting them) instead of unit tests (with mocks).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, in case of legacy code which is running on production, code refactoring to write new unit test cases is NOT the way to go.

Instead, it would be better to first write the unit test cases for the existing code and check-in. With the safety-net in place then onwards (that you have to make all the unit test cases pass at all steps), you can refactor your code (and test cases) in small steps. Goal of these refactoring steps should be to make the code follow the best OOP design principles.

Spending time in writing new unit test cases for a legacy codebase is the biggest disadvantage of working with legacy codebase.